# Mutation-Selection-Drift Equilibrium

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, population-dynamics, population-biology, population-genetics

mutation-selection-drift equilibrium is one of the most important concept of population genetics. I could easily find the calculations for mutation-secltion equilibrium and for mutation-drift equilibrium but not for mutation-selection-drift equilibrium.

---

**mutation-selection equilibrium**

At mutation-selection equilibrium the expected frequency $p$ of a given allele is

$$p ≈ \frac{\mu}{s\cdot h}$$

, where $\mu$ is the mutation rate, $s$ is the selection coefficient and $h$ is the coefficient of dominance.

**mutation-drift equilibrium**

At mutation-drift equilibrium the expected frequency $p$ of a given allele is

$$p ≈ \frac{1}{4N\mu+1} $$

, where $N$ is the population size.

**What is the allelic frequency at mutation-selection-drift equilibrium?**

Comment: I think this paper might be relevant. From what I can see they derive an analytical approx for deleterious allele frequency in MSD equilibrium.http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1894624/

Comment: Drift doesn't change the expected frequency of alleles. In your equation for the mutation-drift equilibrium, I don't think that $f$ is an allele frequency -- it's the homozygosity.

Comment: "expected frequency f of a given locus is" are you sure this is correct? do you mean frequency of an allele rather than locus? According to Charlesworth & Charlesworth it should be $q^*$ which is the equilibrium frequency of $A_2$ the mutant **allele**

Comment: (I'm concerned with the definition not the notation - I've seen $f$ used elsewhere)

Comment: Oh I missed your comment for some reason. You are right "frequency of a locus" makes no sense. I corrected it. Also I replaced $f$ by $p$ as $p$ (or $x$) are more often used to represent allele frequency. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my previous comment -- I also was talking about the definition, not the notation. Your mutation-drift equilibrium equation is for the homozygosity at a locus, not the frequency of an allele. Drift does not change the expected frequency of alleles. So your first equation is valid for mut-sel-drift equilibrium... with one caveat: the actual equation you wrote down is just the strong selection limit of the exact equation, so if drift is too strong it won't be valid.

Comment: Oh I got the point. Can you develop your comment into an answer by clearly stating what are the expected homozygosity and allele frequency under the different scenarios of mutation-selection balance and mutation-selection-drift balance? Thanks a lot.